# How to display only one time Login and then after start application directly in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am getting trouble in making only one time login... My aim is first user gets login screen.. If he is new user he will register and then login...from then when ever user starts the application he should directly redirect to main activity that is to skip the login page..please friends help me out from this problem..please post me any tutorials or any code...please tell me how to modify in manifest file also...

I am using like this in login activity but i didn't achieve my task.

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
pref = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("register","true");
editor.commit();
String getStatus=pref.getString("register", "nil");
if(getStatus.equals("true"))
   // redirect to next activity
else
   // show registration page again
```

Comment: Use SharedPreferences

Comment: debug and check your getstatus value.

Comment: Can you put some more code of your loginscreen  ?

Comment: Not an answer to your query but a suggestion if you consider - Use a boolean variable instead for your getStatus() of user.

Comment: but i need when application is killed also it should not ask for login...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check it here

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

A very good example of session management in android app.

Comment: This does not seems to an answer, because that example does not answer the user's question.

Comment: If you have perfect answer than just post it...in my opinion it's a good way to manage session in android app and that's what the user want.

Comment: In that example i don't see any screen which sends user to second activity using shared preference it is just simple login example.

Comment: check the example properly...you will find main activity. In that activity they check user's session, if not available then redirect to log-in screen. I think its clear now.

Comment: Okay, sorry My mistake, +1 to you.

Answer (score 7):

Implement your `SharedPreferences` this way:

```
Boolean isFirstTime;

SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Splash.this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

isFirstTime = app_preferences.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true);

if (isFirstTime) {

//implement your first time logic
editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
editor.commit();

}else{
//app open directly
}
```

Comment: what is first time logic??

Comment: Means implementing login activity??

Answer (score 3):

Use [SharedPreferences. contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) which tell an key is present or not in SharedPreferences. Change your code as:

```
   SharedPreferences pref;
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
   pref = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
   editor = pref.edit();
   if(pref.contains("register"))
    {
         String getStatus=pref.getString("register", "nil");
          if(getStatus.equals("true")){
             redirect to next activity
           }else{
            //first time
             editor.putString("register","true");
             editor.commit();
           ///  show registration page again
           }
    }
    else{ //first time
             editor = pref.edit();
             editor.putString("register","true");
             editor.commit();
           ///  show registration page again
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit my blog

http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-working-with-shared-preferences.html

hope you will get the answer and understanding clearly

```
Boolean flag;

SharedPreferences applicationpreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = applicationpreferences .edit();

flag = applicationpreferences .getBoolean("flag", false);

if (flag) {
///second time activity

}else{
//first time
editor.putBoolean("flag", true);
editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Session Management in Android](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm) which shows you the way how you can manage the login if user is already logged into the application or not. And switch the user accordingly.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

1.for storing in stored preferences use this

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("DeviceTokenkey","ABABABABABABABB12345");
editor.apply();
```

2.for retrieving the same use

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken", 
 MODE_PRIVATE);
    String deviceToken = prefs.getString("DeviceTokenkey", null);
```