# How to login one time in android application?

Tags: android, authentication, session-management

I am allowing registered users to access the app. The users have to login every time they open the app. So I want to know how to login the app single time like facebook or whatsapp?

Comment: use sheared preference for this purpose.

Comment: I guess this really depends on how you implemented your backend, can you give us more details as how and what you used to implement the login?

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980324/how-to-display-only-one-time-login-and-then-after-start-application-directly-in

Comment: @TPWang I am storing the users who are registered into  server. and need to allow that users when login.And if the users already logged in. I need to open the app.. otherwise make login screen visible.

Comment: @Prasanna Most of the third party database has this function, if you are to implement yourself then yes sharedpreferences, you could also run an Async task in the background to check the status against the server, and enter which ever screen depending on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***Shared Preferences*** .

Android provides many ways of storing data of an application. One of this way is called [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of `key,value pair`.

[SO Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980324/how-to-display-only-one-time-login-and-then-after-start-application-directly-in) .

- You can save and retrieve key, value pair data from Shared
  preferences. SharedPreferences values will persist across user
  sessions.
- Data in shared preferences will be persistent even though user closes
  the application.
- You can get values from Shared preferences using
  getSharedPreferences() method.
- You also need an editor to edit and save the changes in shared
  preferences.
- Use SharedPreferences to store data: booleans, floats, ints, longs,
  and strings.

Demo

1. [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)
2. [Android Working with Shared Preferences](http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-working-with-shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the successful login action.

**Saving the state in Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("username", "yourUserName");
 editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true );
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving the state from SharedPreference**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean isLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
if (isLoggedIn) {
       // Don't display login activity
} else {
      // Display Login Activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_api = "apikey";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    private static final String push_ = "AndroidHivePref";
    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String name, String apikey) {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);


        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_api, apikey);


        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getMerchentPushCount() {
        return pref.getInt("MerchentPushCount", 0);
    }

    public void setMerchentPushCount(Integer count) {
        editor.putInt("MerchentPushCount", count);

        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();


        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        // user api key
        user.put(KEY_api, pref.getString(KEY_api, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |

                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * *
     */
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }


}
```

create a class for sheared prefrence, and call it in ur activity which u wants to make as a landing page. for reference follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) tutorial