# Android One-time Login screen using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am Wondering about One-time screens... I know, I should use something like SharedPreferences or stuff like that.

If someone has a simple solution for one-time login screen. And a little example.

My login contains: weight, name , height, age and gender (spinner)

Comment: You might want to refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238532/how-to-launch-activity-only-once-when-app-is-opened-for-first-time

Comment: Already checked [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980324/how-to-display-only-one-time-login-and-then-after-start-application-directly-in)?

Comment: Pretty good, but it really didn't help me at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at *Android User info and Sign in* :

https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/index.html

Or you can use login with Facebook API.

Otherwise, I would use Shared prefs.

**Create a shared prefs file**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will create a private file for the current activity. You can use MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE if it fits your needs.

You can also provide a file name as the first parameter if needed :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences("com.example.stackoverflow.myfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**Write a shared pref**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("USERNAME", "test");

editor.commit();
```

You can put any primitive type : int, string, boolean, etc.

It is a key/value set. the key string "USERNAME" will then have a value of "test".

**Read shared pref**

```
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("USERNAME", "NO NAME");
```

The second parameter is a default value to use if the key "USERNAME" didn't get any value.

Comment: Have you idea for the non-Facebook or google one-time login because I am a beginner in this SharedPrefences

Comment: So you need to learn how to use Shared prefs or to find another solution ?

Comment: Learn SharedPrefences

Comment: But how does this effect to the one-time screen?

Comment: I really know about storing to shared prefs but what about the "one-time screen part/code"?

Comment: If shared prefs don't return default values, it means your are already connected...

Comment: Does this work if you have to save data and use it on another classes??

Comment: Shared Preferences work on any classes, but you have to give a name like getSharedPreferences("myName", MODE_PRIVATE);